# Navigate through nested JSON-Data on click

Tags: json, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

### Situation

I have complex JSON-data that I want to filter and rearrange. My data is a deeply nested collection of projects. Each project has `task_lists`, which contain `tasks`.

So the structure of my JSON-tree is roughly like this: **projects → task_lists → tasks**

### Result I'd like to achieve

My goal is to view a grid of cards for each project. If I click on a button in project-card I want to change view and show the tasklists of the chosen project and a back-button. If I click on a tasklist, I want to change view and show the tasks of the chosen tasklist and a back-button. If I click on the task, I want to show a detail view of the card and a back-button.

### Code sample

As the JSON is very big and not very readable it is hard to provide a code sample here on StackOverflow. I prepared [a CodeSandbox to better describe how my data looks like](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-navigate-through-nested-json-i30yw?file=/src/components/Project.vue). The projects are imported via the file `projects.json` for the sake of simplicity.

### What I tried so far

I created nested components, but didn't manage to traverse the JSON tree up and down. Then I tried to integrate a vue router, but didn't know how to wire data to the routes.

#### Question

What would be a best practice approach for this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create vue-router with 3 pages, first for your home page that  shows your project list, and 2nd page for the project page, and 3rd will be your TaskLists page

```js
const routes = [
  {
    name: "home",
    path: "/",
    component: () => import("./pages/Home.vue")
  },
  {
    name: "project",
    path: "/project/:projectId",
    component: () => import("./pages/Project.vue"),
    props: true
  },
  {
    name: "taskLists",
    path: "/project/:projectId/tasks",
    component: () => import("./pages/TaskLists.vue"),
    props: true
  }
];
```

So your `App.vue` will only contain `<router-view>`, and your main page will be moved to `Home.vue`.

Then add on `Project.vue` component to push to project page when you click View project, you also need to send the `projectId` as parameter

```js
showProject(id) {
      this.$router.push({
        name: "project",
        params: {
          projectId: this.project.id
        }
      });
    }
```

Add `Project` page that get the `projectId` from parameter, and find the data from JSON, I used computed property for this

```js
  props: ["projectId"],
  computed: {
    project() {
      return projectsData.find(p => p.id === parseInt(this.projectId, 10));
    }
  },
```

Add `TaskLists` page which works similarly with Project page, but you just showing the Task Lists.

```js
  props: ["projectId"],
  computed: {
    taskLists() {
      return projectsData.find(p => p.id === parseInt(this.projectId, 10))
        .task_lists.data;
    }
  },
```

For the go back button, simply use `router-link`, where if you press `Go Back` button on `Project` page, it will go back to `Home` page:

```html
<router-link :to="{name:'home'}">Go back</router-link>
```

And if you press `Go Back` button on `TaskLists` page, it will go back to `Project` page and pass `projectId` as the parameter:

```html
<router-link :to="{name:'project', params: {projectId}}">Go back</router-link>
```

Full working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-navigate-through-nested-json-forked-fd27x